# Getting the correct type information for a function returning a function-pointer that uses variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, variadic-functions, pointer-to-member

I have a variadic function defined within class Foo

```
AddCodeChunkInner(Type, DerivativeStatus, bInlined, Format, args...);
```

And I am trying to write a function that returns its function pointer

```
static auto getAddCodeChunkInner(){return &Foo::AddCodeChunkInner;}
```

However I'm getting an error stating that it "cannot deduce type for 'auto' from 'overloaded-function'.

I believe the solution should look something like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
static auto getAddCodeChunkInner(Args...) -> decltype(int32 (Foo::*) (EMaterialValueType Type, EDerivativeStatus DerivativeStatus, bool bInlined, const TCHAR* Format, ...))
```

I'm struggling a little bit to find the correct syntax here though. I have the general idea, but my knowledge of templates is a bit lacking

minimum reproducible example:

```
class FHLSLMaterialTranslator : public FMaterialCompiler
{
int32 AddCodeChunkInner(uint64 Hash, const TCHAR* FormattedCode, EMaterialValueType Type, EDerivativeStatus DerivativeStatus, bool bInlined);
}

int32 FHLSLMaterialTranslator::AddCodeChunkInner(uint64 Hash, const TCHAR* FormattedCode, EMaterialValueType Type, EDerivativeStatus DerivativeStatus, bool bInlined)
{
    return 1;
}

class myHLSLMaterialTranslator : public FHLSLMaterialTranslator
{
public:
    static auto getAddCodeChunkInner(){return &FHLSLMaterialTranslator::AddCodeChunkInner;}
};
```

Comment: Can you show a [mre], instead of incomplete code snippets. Although the problem here seems to be obvious (spoiler alert: C++ does not work this way, fundamentally), a [mre] is necessary to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: A variadic function and a variadic template are different things. It is not clear which you are referring to. The error message also says that there are multiple overloads that you don't mention. You cannot make a function pointer from a function template, only from one of its specializations. Please show your use case as well.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've added a minimal reproducible example. I hope this helps.

Comment: The code you are showing now will compile without error and there are no templates.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah I am aware that I can only make a function pointer from one of the specializations. Can I use templates to always get a function pointer to the correct specialization?

Comment: @kriNon What is the "correct" specialization? That's why a [mre] demonstrating how you want to use this function would be helpful. (Also, in your example code there is now no template at all.)

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah I am seeing that. I'm a bit confused why my minimal reproducible example is working, but my actual code is throwing an error.

I'll update the reproducible example to be more similar to my code, with less abstraction. Hopefully this helps to make the issue more obvious.

Comment: The code shown now does not compile, with an avalanche of errors that does not appear to have anything remotely to do with the question that was originally asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your problem is, it's nothing to do with the function being variadic or the return type of your function being inferred.  The following code compiles with no problem on gcc, clang, and MSVC:

```
struct S
{
  void f(int, ...) { }
};

static auto getF() { return &S::f; }
```

Given the error message you're describing, it sounds like maybe the problem is instead that you have more than one function in `Foo` called `AddCodeChunkInner`.  If that's the case, you can explicitly specify which overload you're talking about by doing a cast which the desired overload will be the best match for:

```
struct T
{
  void g(int) { }
  void g(int, ...) { }
};

static auto getG1() { return static_cast<void(T::*)(int)>(&T::g); }

static auto getG2() { return static_cast<void(T::*)(int, ...)>(&T::g); }
```

Comment: I think you are correct. I have:
    `int32 AddCodeChunkInner(uint64 Hash, const TCHAR* FormattedCode, EMaterialValueType Type, EDerivativeStatus DerivativeStatus, bool bInlined);`

and

    `int32 AddCodeChunkInner(EMaterialValueType Type, EDerivativeStatus DerivativeStatus, bool bInlined, const TCHAR* Format, ...);`